# How to Use Crosstab with dynamic number of columns by making use of Join Clause In PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgres-crosstab

I am trying to get Table Data in a vertical way using **Crosstab**. To be more precise, I need to group by prefix and postfix at the same time and get summ. In this case I should Join 2 tables and get names for unique prefix and postfix. Number of Columns may vary depending on **income_account_setting** table values. In my case I have more than 20 different names meaning that I should have code_account and 20 columns. I tried to do with the help of **Crosstab**, But on the internet examples are given for fixed number of columns

My Tables:
**main_client_profit**

```
id     |  code_account      | summa       | prefix     | postfix  |   oper_month   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      |  04315187          | 72871232.77 | 45233      |  222     |  2020-04       |
2      |  00524154          | 89753426.58 | 45294      |  100     |  2020-01       |
3      |  02115187          | 23224345.89 | 45249      |  204     |  2020-03       |
4      |  00388996          | 119030.87   | 45294      |  246     |  2020-05       |
5      |  04222959          | 105000.00   | 45233      |  222     |  2020-04       |
6      |  04315187          | 92871232.77 | 45233      |  222     |  2020-04       |
1      |  04222959          | 1020458.40  | 45233      |  421     |  2020-01       |
```

**income_account_setting**

```
id    |  prefix    |  postfix   |  name          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     |  45233     |  222       |   A            |
1     |  45294     |  100       |   B            |
1     |  45249     |  204       |   C            |
1     |  45294     |  246       |   E            |
1     |  45233     |  421       |   F            |
```

**The result I need to take**

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
code_account      | A         | B           |  C          |  D   |    E  |
----------------------------------------------------------
04315187          | 165742465 | 0           |  0          | 0    |   0   |
00524154          |           | 89753426.58 |  0          | 0    |   0   |
02115187          |    0      |             | 23224345.89 | 0    |   0   |

and etc ....
```

What I tried so far but it does not work

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab('SELECT m.code_account, a.name, evaluation_result 
        FROM main_client_profit m
             INNER JOIN income_account_setting a 
            ON m.prefix = a.prefix AND m.postfix = a.postfix
        GROUP BY CONCAT(m.prefix,m.postfix)
        ORDER BY 1,2') 
   AS final_result(code character varying(20),)
```

In above code I don`t know what to write inside final_result as columns.

Is it possible to do this task with Crosstab? Or is there any other way to do it Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but `GROUP BY CONCAT(m.prefix,m.postfix)` is a bad idea, as it will result in wrong grouping. It will treat `12,1` the same as `1,21` which is not what you want. You should use group by all columns individually: `group by m.prefix, m.postfix`

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is, that the `crosstab()` function typically complicates things more then it helps. And it can't overcome the limitation that all columns of the result must be known **before** the statement is run.

I would do it like this:

```
SELECT m.code_account,
       sum(m.summa) filter (where a.name = 'A') as "A",
       sum(m.summa) filter (where a.name = 'B') as "B",
       sum(m.summa) filter (where a.name = 'C') as "C",
       sum(m.summa) filter (where a.name = 'D') as "D",
       sum(m.summa) filter (where a.name = 'E') as "E"
FROM main_client_profit m
  LEFT JOIN income_account_setting a
         ON m.prefix = a.prefix 
        AND m.postfix = a.postfix
GROUP BY m.code_account
ORDER BY m.code_account
```

Comment: Thank you for help. This answer is more simpler compared to crosstab, but when I add new data into ```income_account_setting``` then I also need to update query as well.

Comment: @Abdusoli: that's correct, and using `crosstab()` wouldn't solve that problem. It's an intrinsic limitation of SQL that the number of resulting columns must be known before the database runs the statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can pack/unpack using JSON, but you need to restore the correct datatype.

[this is not truly dynamic, you still have to type in the list of column names. Thus could be automated wih dynamic SQL]

---

```
WITH omg AS ( -- Pack into json
        SELECT m.code_account
        , json_object_agg(a.name, summa) AS zooi
        FROM main_client_profit m
        JOIN income_account_setting a
        ON m.prefix = a.prefix AND m.postfix = a.postfix
        GROUP BY m.code_account
        ORDER BY 1
        )
SELECT o.code_account -- And unpack it. Still need to cast to the wanted type
        , (o.zooi->>'A')::DECIMAL(10,2) AS A
        , (o.zooi->>'B')::DECIMAL(10,2) AS B
        , (o.zooi->>'C')::DECIMAL(10,2) AS C
        , (o.zooi->>'D')::DECIMAL(10,2) AS D
        , (o.zooi->>'E')::DECIMAL(10,2) AS E
        , (o.zooi->>'F')::DECIMAL(10,2) AS F
FROM omg o
ORDER BY 1
        ;
```